# Here API's Report Usage is not available

Tags: here-api

I'm using freemium plan but report usage data is not available. How I can view daily report usage?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the usage details by apply the filter on right side of the same page from where you have taken this screenshot above. Once you select the date or from-to then you can see the result in bottom , also you can download the result into csv format to see for every day usage.

[image]

Comment: It just shows `We’re showing you your usage data as soon as we have it, which means occasionally there may be small changes as we validate it.
Rest assured your monthly invoices will contain fully validated data.`